# Issue with content and overflow: hidden with animation in background when window is made smaller

Tags: html, css

So I have an animation (clouds) that runs from off the left side of the screen (margin-left:-1000px) to the right side of the screen (margin-left: 100%). In order to prevent the horizontal scroll from popping up, I have set the overflow-x of the body to hidden. I have content centered on top of the background animation, and I have set the min-width of the body to 1000px. I need to preserve the min-width of the body for another animation that I need to have, so I can't just get rid of that for the "simple" solution. Anyways, the issue is that when I resize the window to a size smaller than 1000px wide, my content will eventually just get chopped off due to the overflow setting and be rendered un-readable. Does anybody have some sort of workaround I could do to preserve what I have?

HTML

```
<body>
 <div id="background-wrap">
    <div class="x1">
        <div class="cloud"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">
        <span class="header-text">hello</span>
        <span class="header-sub-text">world!</span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
min-width: 1000px;
background-color: #D6F3FF;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

@keyframes animateCloud {
0% { margin-left: -1000px; }
100% { margin-left: 100%; }
}

.x1 {
animation: animateCloud 35s linear infinite;
transform: scale(0.65);
}

.cloud {
background: #fff;
border-radius: 100px;
height: 120px;
position: relative;
width: 350px;
}

.header-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
}
.header {
background-color: #7CED99;
width: 60%;
height: 275px;
text-align: center;
}
```

I have thought about doing something with @media once the window reaches the min-width, and I have tried messing with the div that holds the background animation like such where the overflow for this is set to hidden and the width is set to 100%, but when I shrink the window and then restore it to the original size it will leave the width at the shrunken size and cut off part of the animation.

```
#background-wrap {
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding-top: 70px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: -1;
height: 1000px;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Let me know if you can come up with any sort of solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets) or [**create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to someone to provide you any help.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup, just updated original query

Comment: why are you using `margin` whereas you can easily do this with `@keyframes animateCloud { 0% { transform: translateX(0%); } 100% { transform: translateX(100%);} }` and simply use `overflow-x: hidden;` there's no use for `min-width: 1000px;`, in my opinion.

Comment: I wanted to start the clouds off the screen to smoothly come in, hence the initial inclination to use negative margins. I can remove the min-width and everything will be fine, but I want to keep that for a specific animation that I am using further into my site that requires the screen to have a minimum width size of 1000px or so (otherwise the animation gets messed up instead).